# Accessing scope variable from controller in a directive in angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular.module('app')
    .controller('someController', ['$scope','localStorageService',someController])
    .directive('someDirective', someDirective)

function someController($scope, localStorageService){
    $scope.something = {
        someVar: localStorageService.get('someVar'),
    };
    console.log("someVar: " + $scope.something.someVar);//prints correct value
}

function someDirective(){
    return {
        template: {{something.someVar}}
    };
}

})();
```

In the html, where

```
<div ng-controller="someController"> 
    <div some-directive></div>    
</div>
```

is added, I keep getting a "Argument 'someController' is not a function, got undefined" even though someController executes fine when printing to console.

Comment: is the line `template: {{something.someVar}}` a mistype here or are you really missing the quotes? should be: `template: '{{something.someVar}}'`.

Comment: @Claies Ahhh yess that's what it was!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an error in the declaration of the template for the directive here.

`template: {{something.someVar}}` is missing the quotes.

It should be: `template: '{{something.someVar}}'`

Answer (score 0):

can you try this ?
this should be working

```
.controller('someController',someController)
.directive('someDirective', someDirective);

someController.$inject = ['$scope','localStorageService'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the line that creates the controller and the directive to underneath the function declarations:

```
function someController($scope, localStorageService){
    $scope.something = {
        someVar: localStorageService.get('someVar'),
    };
    console.log("someVar: " + $scope.something.someVar);//prints correct value
}

function someDirective(){
    return {
        template: {{something.someVar}}
    };
}

angular.module('app')
    .controller('someController', ['$scope','localStorageService',someController])
    .directive('someDirective', someDirective);
```

Comment: ^ not necessary and not the cause of the problem. also, sort of an ugly coding convention. your issue resides elsewhere.